# Document, Min and Max for specific field with spring data elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using Spring Data ElasticSearch and trying to get distinct documents with a min and max value for one of the fields.  I also need the document associated with the Max Value.

Based on some examples I've found and a bit of tinkering, I came up with this, but I'm not quite sure where to go from here or if this will achieve what I am looking for.

```
TermsBuilder termBuilder = AggregationBuilders.terms("check_id");
    MaxBuilder maxBuilder = AggregationBuilders.max("exec_time_epoch");
    MinBuilder minBuilder = AggregationBuilders.min("exec_time_epoch");

    termBuilder.subAggregation(maxBuilder);
    termBuilder.subAggregation(minBuilder);

    SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
        .withQuery(matchAllQuery())
        .addAggregation(termBuilder)
        .build();

    Aggregations aggregations = elasticsearchTemplate.query(searchQuery, new ResultsExtractor<Aggregations>() {
        @Override
        public Aggregations extract(SearchResponse response) {
            return response.getAggregations();
        }
    });
```

I'm not sure how to get the min and max values or the document associated with the max value from this.

**Update:**

With your help, I was able to figure out how to get this done.  Here is my full code in case it might help someone in the future.

```
 public List<CamAlertDetail> findOldestAndNewest(String category) {

    TermsBuilder termBuilder = AggregationBuilders.terms("agg_terms").field("check_id");

    TopHitsBuilder topHitsBuilder = AggregationBuilders.topHits("maxDoc")
        .setSize(1)
        .addSort("exec_time_epoch", SortOrder.DESC);

    TopHitsBuilder topHitsBuilder2 = AggregationBuilders.topHits("minDoc")
        .setSize(1)
        .addSort("exec_time_epoch", SortOrder.ASC);

    termBuilder.subAggregation(topHitsBuilder);
    termBuilder.subAggregation(topHitsBuilder2);

    QueryBuilder queryBuilder;
    if (category != null) {
        queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("categories", category));
    } else {
        queryBuilder = matchAllQuery();
    }

    SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
        .withQuery(queryBuilder)
        .withIndices("caam-results")
        .addAggregation(termBuilder)
        .build();
    Aggregations aggregations = elasticsearchTemplate.query(searchQuery, new ResultsExtractor<Aggregations>() {
        @Override
        public Aggregations extract(SearchResponse response) {
            return response.getAggregations();
        }
    });

    Terms terms = aggregations.get("agg_terms");

    List<CamAlertDetail> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Terms.Bucket bucket : terms.getBuckets()) {
        TopHits min = bucket.getAggregations().get("minDoc");
        TopHits max = bucket.getAggregations().get("maxDoc");

        CamAlertDetail detail = new CamAlertDetail();
        detail.setOldest(createAlertFromSearchHit(min.getHits().getAt(0)));
        detail.setNewest(createAlertFromSearchHit(max.getHits().getAt(0)));
        list.add(detail);
    }

    return list;


}
    private CamAlert createAlertFromSearchHit(SearchHit hit) {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        return mapper.readValue(hit.sourceAsString(), CamAlert.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Error Converting json to cam alert.", e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right path, you only need to get the one document that has the maximum `exec_time_epoch` value, and for that you can add another [`top_hits` sub-aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) inside the `terms` aggregation for `check_id` that takes a single document sorted in decreasing order of `exec_time_epoch`.

```
TermsBuilder termBuilder = AggregationBuilders.terms("check_id");
MaxBuilder maxBuilder = AggregationBuilders.max("exec_time_epoch");
MinBuilder minBuilder = AggregationBuilders.min("exec_time_epoch");

termBuilder.subAggregation(maxBuilder);
termBuilder.subAggregation(minBuilder);

// ADD THIS: add another top_hits sub-aggregation which
// - takes a single document
// - sorted by exec_time_epoch desc
TopHitsBuilder topHitsBuilder = AggregationBuilders.topHits("maxDoc")
    .setSize(1)
    .addSort("exec_time_epoch", SortOrder.DESC);
termBuilder.subAggregation(topHitsBuilder);

SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
    .withQuery(matchAllQuery())
    .addAggregation(termBuilder)
    .build();

Aggregations aggregations = elasticsearchTemplate.query(searchQuery, new ResultsExtractor<Aggregations>() {
    @Override
    public Aggregations extract(SearchResponse response) {
        return response.getAggregations();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, you lead me to the solution in my edit!